# Unable to get my script to return ContentService

Tags: google-apps-script

Let me just preface this with I know this script could probably be better but I'm very new to scripting in any language and I'm just playing around with an idea for work. This is essentially just a frankensteined combination of google results for what I want to accomplish but I've hit a deadend.

I'm using an aspect from another script to return contentservice in JSON format for a webapp except it's not working in this case

As far as I can tell it should work perfectly fine and if I replace the return contentservice with the browser.msgbox below I get the values returned that I want but when using contentservice and going to my scripts [Web App URL](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxnieC5bFkT7oxBn_UrnxPTw9dBcW3fRbdR1IKMfw/exec?action=Range) with the action pointing to range I get the error The script completed but did not return anything.

```
var mysheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sPuqdg0Va9LLQudl2ta23b-CGEF_-FFSTeggRw3J4L4/edit").getSheetByName('Sheet3');
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sPuqdg0Va9LLQudl2ta23b-CGEF_-FFSTeggRw3J4L4/edit").getSheetByName('Sheet1');


function doGet(e){
var action = e.parameter.action;

 if(action == 'Range'){
   return Range(e);
 }
}


function Range(e) {
 let term = 'Customer 6';
 var sdata = mysheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
 sdata.forEach((val, index) => {
    if(val == term){
        var msgr = "B" + (index+1)
        var msgc = "D" + (index+1)
        var rrow = mysheet.getRange(msgr).getValue();
        var ccol = mysheet.getRange(msgc).getValue();
        var data = sheet.getRange("E" + rrow + ":I"+ccol);  
        var records={};
        var rows = sheet.getRange("E" + rrow + ":I"+ccol).getValues();
        data = []; 
 for (var r = 0, l = rows.length; r < l; r++) {
   var row     = rows[r],
       record  = {};
   record['Product'] = row[0];
   record['Case']=row[2];
   record['Order QTY']=row[3];
   record['Packed']=row[4];
   
   data.push(record);
   
 }
 records.items = data;  
 var result=JSON.stringify(records);
 return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
 // Browser.msgBox(result);
 }})}
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting the correct returned values for the msgBox, but no results for the ContentService.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I have been publishing new webapp versions every revision

Comment: You need to republish your webapp after making any changes

Comment: Sorry I should of mentioned that in the post I'll update it now, but yes I have been republishing new versions every time I make a change i want to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This breaks because you're returning from within a `forEach()` loop. Check out the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong tool.

The simplest fix is to use a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) instead.

```
function Range(e) {
  let term = 'Customer 6';
  var sdata = mysheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  for (var index = 0; index < sdata.length; index++) {
    var val = sdata[index];
    if(val == term){
      var msgr = "B" + (index+1)
      var msgc = "D" + (index+1)
      var rrow = mysheet.getRange(msgr).getValue();
      var ccol = mysheet.getRange(msgc).getValue();
      var data = sheet.getRange("E" + rrow + ":I"+ccol);  
      var records={};
      var rows = sheet.getRange("E" + rrow + ":I"+ccol).getValues();
      data = []; 
      for (var r = 0, l = rows.length; r < l; r++) {
        var row     = rows[r],
            record  = {};
        record['Product'] = row[0];
        record['Case']=row[2];
        record['Order QTY']=row[3];
        record['Packed']=row[4];
        
        data.push(record);
        
      }
      records.items = data;  
      var result=JSON.stringify(records);
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }
  }
}
```